# ggplot2 annotate text with a plot symbol

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, annotations, symbols

I would like to a legend to a ggplot2 plot. The legend should identify the plotting symbol with the data. 
For example, data1 is plotted with a filled square and data2 is plotted with a filled circle.

Is there a way to do this?

The example below from a previous stackoverflow question worked where one adds a math (perp.) symbol.

```
p <- p + annotate("text",2005,5, label="E(y)*symbol('\\136')*b", parse=TRUE)
```

Comment: Please add a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example helps:

```
df <- mtcars[,c(5,6,9)]
df[,3] <- as.factor(df[,3])
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=drat,y=wt, fill=am, shape=am)) +  
            geom_point(size=4)+scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22))
```

Here's the plot:
[image]

The values 21 and 22 refer to filled circle and filled square, respectively. See `?points` for the complete list of available symbols.

Comment: Thank you. I meant to add annotation to the plot (just as does the legend, i.e., showing a symbol for each plotted dataset). I will work from the example you provided and see if I could solve it.